# Memory saving way to perform linear solving in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I am doing some computation using pytorch, there is a Jacobian matrix, which is J, of a vector of equations, r, and I am using jacfwd (pytorch.functorch) to calculate it, then there will be a linear solving

```
        r      = get_residual(unknown)
        J      = jacfwd(get_residual)(unknown)
        update       = torch.linalg.solve(J, r)
```

I actually don’t need J to be explicit, and J can be a huge sparse matrix. How to use like COO or CSR matrix to save memory and speed up this process in pytorch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert J to a sparse matrix in CSR format which is sparse matrix format. something like this:

```
import scipy.sparse as sp

r = get_residual(unknown)
J = jacfwd(get_residual)(unknown)
J_sparse = sp.csr_matrix(J.detach().numpy())

update = sp.linalg.spsolve(J_sparse, r.detach().numpy())
update_tensor = torch.tensor(update, dtype=torch.float32)
```

Comment: Hi, is there any way to do sparse solve using torch instead of scipy.sparse?